# Show that $|x|^{-1/2}$ is not weakly differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

My general question is how one shows the non-existence of weak derivatives for $L^1$-functions where integration by parts fails because the strong derivative, though it exists, is not $L^1$-integrable.

As an example, consider the real interval $(-1,1)$ and the function $f$ thereon
with $f(x) = |x|^{-1/2}$. Then $f$ is an $L^1$ function, but its strong derivative (away from $0$) fails
to be locally $L^1$-integrable. How do I show that it is not weakly differentiable, i.e. that there does not exist any locally $L^1$-integrable function $g$ such that for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty(-1,1)$:
$$\int_{-1}^1 |x|^{-1/2} \, \phi'(x) \,  \operatorname{d} \negthinspace \, x = - \int_{-1}^1 g(x) \phi(x) \,  \operatorname{d} \negthinspace \, x \, .$$

It is clear to me that one needs to argue via a contraction, assuming the existence of $g$. I know in similar problems one chooses a suitable sequence of functions $\phi_k \in C_c^\infty(-1,1)$ with $k \in \mathbb N$ to obtain the contradiction, but I have not gotten it to work here...

Comment: The $g$ in question is $-\frac{1}{2} x^{-3/2}$ anyway, the issue is whether it is as regular as you want it to be. For $C^\infty_c$ test functions it's a valid distribution.

Comment: I fixed the interval and changed to $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$. Everything should make sense now. The choice above does not work because of lack of integrability (that's the point of the question).

Comment: Sorry, $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{|x|}$, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by taking functions $\phi$ that are zero in $(-\delta,\delta)$. Then you can integrate by parts in the classical sense and the function $g$ has to be the standard derivative of $f$ outside of $(-\delta,\delta)$. Then you let $\delta$ go to zero and find that $g$ is the standard derivative of $f$ except at one point, which is irrelevant when it comes to integrability.
**EDIT: I added more details, in view of the comments**

Assume that $f$ has a weak derivative $g$ in $L^{1}((-1,1))$. Take
$0<\delta<1$ and a function $\phi\in C_{c}^{1}((-1,1))$, which is zero in
$(-\delta,\delta)$. Then
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)\phi^{\prime}(x)\,dx=-\int_{-1}^{1}g(x)\phi(x)\,dx
$$
by the definition of weak derivative, and by standard integration by
parts
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)\phi^{\prime}(x)\,dx=-\int_{-1}^{1}f^{\prime}(x)\phi(x)\,dx
$$
because $f$ is $C^{1}$ in $[-1,1]\setminus(-\delta,\delta)$. Subtracting these
two identities, you get
$$
0=\int_{-1}^{1}(g(x)-f^{\prime}(x))\phi(x)\,dx
$$
for all $\phi\in C_{c}^{1}((-1,1))$ that are zero in $(-\delta,\delta)$. Since
these functions are dense in $L^{1}((-1,1)\setminus(-\delta,\delta))$, you get
that $g(x)-f^{\prime}(x)=0$ a.e. in $(-1,1)\setminus(-\delta,\delta)$. Hence,
if you let $\delta\rightarrow0^{+}$, you get that $g=f^{\prime}$ a.e., which
is a contradiction, since $f^{\prime}$ is not integrable.

Comment: This is not really a rigorous proof and your conclusion is false (the limit as $\delta \to 0$ of the right hand side will diverge). But the idea may actually work, if argued correctly. I will try to construct a rigorous argument later today.

Comment: This is a rigorous proof. I didn’t say that you let $\delta$ go to zero in the integral. I just said that if the weak derivative $g$ exists, then it coincides with the classical derivative $f’$ in $(-1,1)\setminus (-\delta,\delta)$. So if you let $\delta$ go to zero or use the arbitrariness of $\delta$, you find that $g$ has to be $f’$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, that looks a lot better. Using the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations was another good idea. Please allow me to clarify the argument at the end: 
For all $1>\delta >0$ we have $f'=g$ on $(-1, \delta) \cup (\delta,1)$. As $g$ is integrable on $(-1,1)$, 
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \int_{(-1, \delta) \cup (\delta,1)} g(x) \, \phi(x) \, d x = \int_{-1}^{1} g(x) \, \phi(x) \, d x < \infty \, .$$
As $f'$ is not integrable on $(-1,1)$, the other integral does not converge. Contradiction. 
Your argument answers the question completely, thank you!

Comment: Sorry to open this up again, but the closing argument in my comment above does not work, because the integral will only diverge if we also increase the support of $\phi$ with $\delta$ decreasing. Otherwise, all we have obtained is that the limit of the two integrals as $\delta \to 0^+$ is equal for all $\phi \in C^1_c((-1,1)\setminus (- \delta_0,\delta_0))$---a correct statement. The last sentence you wrote down seems to be a pseudo-proof, for it is not clear what taking the limit is supposed to mean mathematically.

Comment: I tried to fix your proof by taking two $C^\infty$-bump functions that approach each other as $\delta \to 0$ and then look at the asymptotic behavior of the product with $f'(x)$ at zero. Unfortunately, the `zero of the bump function at the edges' seems to be too strong, so that one cannot get any asymptotic behavior of $x^{-\alpha}$ with $\alpha >0$, let alone $\alpha \geq 1$. The question explicitly asked for the test function space to be $C^\infty_c(-1,1)$.

As of now, the proof is incomplete.

Comment: Take $\delta=1/n$ and find a set $E_n$ of measure zero such that $g=f’$ in $(-1,1)\setminus ((-1/n,1/n)\cup E_n))$ for every $n$. If you take the union of these sets, you get $g=f’$ on $(-1,1)\setminus E$, where $E$ is the union of the sets $E_n$ and $\{0\}$

Comment: I clarified your response in another answer, but accepted this one as the correct answer for it is your argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a cleaned-up version of Gio67's argument above, as I did not want to edit his post and comment there further:

Assume such an integrable $g$ exists. Then for all $\delta >0$ and all $\phi \in C^\infty((-1,1)\setminus(-\delta, \delta))$ we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \phi'(x) \, d x = - 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x) \phi(x) \, d x = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \phi(x) \, d x \, .$$
Taking the difference and applying the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations, we find that for all $\delta >0$ and for almost all $x \in (-1,1) \setminus (-\delta,\delta)$ we have $f'(x)=g(x)$. But this implies that $f'(x)=g(x)$ for almost all $x \in (-1,1) \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. So $f'=g$ almost everywhere on $(-1,1)$. But $g$ was assumed to be integrable, which is a contradiction.